# SQL search query returns no results

Tags: php, mysql

I have three pages search.php that handles the sql query, index.php which has the search form it self and connect.php which has the database connection information. I was following the information from this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gf32KXTP0C4

First I made sure the query would work in phpMyAdmim
[image: query working in mysql] I used a as a test. As you can see it returns 117 results

The form with keywords as the name

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
        <label>
            Search
            <input type="text" name="keywords" autocomplete="off">

        </label>

        <input type="submit" value="Search">
```

Search.php is as follows, it should search the table charactor for what was entered into the form according to they ketwords echo the amout of results and then list them

```
<?php

require_once 'connect.php';

if(isset($_GET['keywords'])) {

     $keywords = $db->escape_string($_GET['keywords']);

     $query = $db->query("
        SELECT charactor_name, vault_number, history
        FROM charactor 
        WHERE charactor_name like '%{keywords}%'
     ");
     ?>

     <div class="result-count">
        Found <?php echo $query->num_rows; ?> results
     </div>


     <?php

     if($query->num_rows) {
         while($r = $query->fetch_object()) {
             ?>
             <div class="result">
             <a href="#"><?php echo $r->charactor_name; ?></a>
             </div>
             <?php


         }


     }

}
```

connect.php is as follows
I used the code from http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php to test the database connection from the if statement down to make sure the connectoion was working. I commented it out once I knew it was working

[image: connection success]

```
<?php 

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'csc8417');
/*
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Success... ' . $db->host_info . "\n";

$db->close();
?>*/
```

No matter what query I run I always get 0 results as shown here

[image: tenpenny]
It should return 
[image: tenpenny2]

Answer (score 3):

please check here:

```
 $query = $db->query("
    SELECT charactor_name, vault_number, history
    FROM charactor 
    WHERE charactor_name like '%{keywords}%'
 ");
```

keywords should be $keywords

Comment: which is interesting given in the video as you can see here they don't have the $ https://i.imgur.com/KULwZfP.png

Comment: i can not check video but in the image which you sent(https://imgur.com/KULwZfP) they used $keywords

Comment: you are correct, they do and I have missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this one?

```
if( $query->num_rows() ) {
```

use `$query->num_rows()` instead of `$query->num_rows` ?